# How to secure multiple select box options?

Tags: php, function, drop-down-menu

Do you need to secure multiple select boxes being that the options are already set rather then user input?

I use this function to secure regular inputs:

```
function keepmesafe($input) 
 {
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() == true)
    {
     $input = stripslashes($input);
   }
   return htmlspecialchars($input);
}
```

but when I use it on multiple select i get this warning:

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array
>   given in ...

I understand the warning it expects a string but gets an array, so if you do need to secure what do I need to change in the current function or has anyone a function for this?

Answer (score 0):

Like the warning says, you are sending an array to a function that only accepts strings.
You should send a single string to the function htmlspecialchars, or modify the function to something like this:

```
    function keepmesafe($input) 
    {
        if(is_array($input))
        {
            foreach($input as $key => $value) 
            {
                $input[$key] = keepmesafe($value); 
            }   
            return $input;
        }


        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() == true)
        {
            $input = stripslashes($input);
        }

        return htmlspecialchars($input);
    }
```

You can find more on user input and security [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).